# first type boolean second type char java error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
if( (mychar == '+' || mychar == '-') && (stack.peek() ==  '+' || stack.peek() = '-') )
```

I am getting the error below:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '||'
first type:  boolean
second type: Character
```

I've checked it several times, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Typo. `stack.peek() = '-')` should be `stack.peek() == '-')`

Answer (score 1):

you forget to add double == to at end.

It should be `stack.peek() == '-'`, not `stack.peek() = '-'`

Comment: Problems caused by a typographical error should be closed as off-topic, not answered.

Comment: ok thanks to let me know my bad

Comment: You're always welcome to help the OP in the comments section, but @Elliott has already done that.